# C# Split String Method separator.length > 1 explain code

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, string, file

I have data like this in a file:

```
AccountNumber#//#PinrCode#//#name#//#PhoneNumber#//#AccountBalance
```

I am using C# split separator that splits the string I get from the file and but the data in the client object, when I have a `separator.length = 1`, everything is fine, but when I have `separator.length > 1`, I get a problem. I solved it like this but I don't really understand the code that I wrote and I have few questions

```
public void ConvertLineToClient(String Line, String Separator = "#//#") 
{
    String[] ClientInfo = Line.Split(new string[] { Separator }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    this.AccountNumber = ClientInfo[0];
    this.PinCode = ClientInfo[1];
    this.Name = ClientInfo[2];
    this.PhoneNumber = ClientInfo[3];
    this.AccountBalance = Convert.ToInt16(ClientInfo[4]);
}
```

I want to understand what does the

```
new string[] { Separator }
```

do?

And what is the other parameter?

Comment: `solve the problem` what's the actual problem? `String.Split` works. You can find out what each parameter does in the [method documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0)? `String.Split` has overloads that accept multiple separators and can eliminate empty strings from the results

Comment: Have you tried `var lines=Line.Split("#//#");`? This returns an array of 5 strings

Comment: You could have just paid attention to Intellisense and not even had to read the documentation. `String.Split` is overloaded and that's one of the overloads. What exactly do you not understand about creating a `string` array?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're still using the .Net Framework.

If the separator contains only 1 character, you can directly pass the separator to the `Split` method as `Line.Split('#')`. That's because the `Split` method group has [the following overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-string-split(system-char())):

```
public string[] Split (params char[] separator);
```

But if the separator contains multiple characters, the separator has to be a `string` object. Unfortunately under the .Net Framework, there is no overload among the `Split` method group that acceptes a `string` or `params string[]` parameter, only the `string[]` type is accepted, that's why you have to construct a string array: `Line.Split(new string[] { Separator })`.

Today in the .Net Core, [a new overload method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0#system-string-split(system-string-system-stringsplitoptions)) has been added, you do not need to create an array anymore.

Comment: Passing a single string is asking for confusion -- anyone reading the code is going to wonder whether it's treated as one multi-character separator, or an `IEnumerable<char>` holding a bunch of alternative single-character separators.   Maybe after the new overload is "in the wild" long enough, programmers will have the right interpretation memorized.

Comment: No wonder .Net didn't initially have a single string, but for me, allocating an array every time is more unbearable compared to confusion.